# How to set column width that table aligns automatic with merged cells?

Tags: tables

What I want to do is make a table in the format that I have showed below. At the moment the width of the columns is different and the table is to wide for the page. It looks as following:
[image]

What I am trying to do is

1) set the table to be as wide as the text, so that it takes up maximum space within the margins

2) set that column 2, 3 and 4 that contain the results are the same width.

```
\begin{table}[H] \centering \caption{X} \label{X}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \textbf{References} & \textbf{Results 1} & \textbf{Results 2} & \textbf{Results 3} \\\hline\hline

    Author (Year)
    & 
    Answer Answer 
    & 
    Answer Answer Answer Answer 
    & 
        \begin{tabular}{c} 
        Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer  \\
        Answer Answer Answer  \\ 
        \end{tabular} 
    \\\hline

    Author (Year) & 
        \begin{tabular}{c} 
        Answer \\ 
        Answer \\ 
        \end{tabular}
    &
    Answer Answer 
    &
        \begin{tabular}{c} 
        Answer Answer Answer  \\ 
        Answer Answer Answer  \\ 
        \end{tabular}
    \\\hline   

    Author (Year) & 
    \begin{tabular}{c} 
    Answer \\ 
    Answer \\ 
    Answer \\ 
    \end{tabular} 
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer }
    \\\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Are you looking for `tabularx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `tabularx` is no need to nest tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{X} 
    \label{X}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} @{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{References} & \textbf{Results 1} & \textbf{Results 2} & \textbf{Results 3}  \\
    \midrule
Author (Year)       
    &  Answer Answer    
        &   Answer Answer Answer Answer
            &   Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer 

                Answer Answer Answer                                                \\
    \midrule
Author (Year) 
    &   Answer 

        Answer
        &   Answer Answer
            &   Answer Answer Answer 
                Answer Answer Answer                                                \\
    \midrule
Author (Year) 
    &   Answer

        Answer

        Answer
        &   \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep\relax
                              \centering\arraybackslash}X}{%
            Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer }               \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

instead of horizontally centered cells text i would rather have left aligned, i.e. instead of `>{\centering\arraybackslash}X` use `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X`

Comment: +1. Since there are no vertical rules in the table, one can (should...) omit the `\arrayrulewidth` adjustment.

Comment: @Mico, during tests it was there, but then i erase it and forget to correct  calculation of columns width. thank you very much!